# How to run sql script in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hi what is the best way to run an sql script in Java? I have my connection to the db and picked up some code that I think may work to run the script getting a few errors currently.

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

private String userName = "";
private String password = "";
private String serverName = "";
private String portNumber = "";




public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;

    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
    connectionProps.put("password", this.password);
    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" +
            this.serverName +
            ":" + this.portNumber;

    System.out.println("Connection String: " + connectionString);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, connectionProps);

    System.out.println("Connected to database");
    return conn;


    **ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn, connectionString, connectionProps)
    String file = "resources/cleanDatabaseScript.sql";
    System.out.println("retreived script");
    runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));**


}
```

The ScriptRunner section is the area im struggling with currently.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Currently this on the scriptRunner line but I did change the original code I copied in to match mine.

Error:(47, 88) java: ';' expected

I added conn, connectionString, connectionProps

Comment: Why line `ScriptRunner runner...` has no `;` at the end?

Comment: Why are you having code after return statement, the return will end the execution inside of the getConnection function, so the the code after return will never be executed

Comment: @Meshredded That makes sense thats a good start. I must note I am still new to java so it's all a learning curve so apologies if it looks amateurish thats probably because it is hence why I'm asking the experts.

Comment: No problem i'm not an expert neither i'll give an answer

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I think it's a good question.

Comment: In case anyone was interested I found my solution right here https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/ScriptRunner using the script runner. All I needed was to add the java file to my project. Works a treat. I have also implemented the below code as it looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic class to connect to a mySql:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DbConnection {

    private static Connection singleConnection ;
    private static Statement  singleStatement;


    public static synchronized Statement getStatement() throws SQLException{

        if (singleConnection == null){
            singleConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://HereTheHost:HereThePortNumber/HereTheDataBaseName","HereTheUserName","HereThePassWord");
            if (singleStatement == null){
                singleStatement = singleConnection.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Connection Success !");
            }
        }
        return singleStatement;
    }

}
```

This example makes sure that you will have only one instance of the database connection, if you don't understand this just ignore it.

Comment: and in order to retreive data from you tables you can see this example : https://github.com/Meshredded/Java8_Planning_Manager/blob/master/sources/src/memoryDatabaseExchange/CoursLoader.java

Comment: Thank you for this it does look a lot cleaner but I think the point has been missed. Whilst you have improved the database connection. I failed to explain I have a file in my project 

String file = "resources/cleanDatabaseScript.sql";

All I need require to do is run the script after the database connection. My fault I didn't explain properly in the original post.

Comment: if you have a file than it must be an sqlite database so you need another driver

Comment: here's the way to do it with sqlite https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc